# Monitor turns on, emits sound, then lcd turns off

Tags: display, repair

My monitor already fell for a few times from my bad (using it like a laptop) but this time the case of the monitor got open. I immediately closed it and when I turn it on:

1. The ligght indicator turns on
2. LCD turns on
3. LCD makes this quick weird sound then displays, then abruptly turns off (no light) after a fraction of a second
4. light indicator still on

Sometimes when I shake the monitor then turn it on, it can remain on for a few seconds but with a buzzing sound. What could be the problem?

Monitor model: viewsonic monitor vx1937wma (it doesn't have any screws and it's so hard opening it)

Comment: The problem is probably because _you dropped it multiple times_? It could be just about anything.

Comment: Probably some part inside the monitor is making a bad contact (best case scenario) or you broke some electronic component (worst case scenario).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that shaking makes it work again suggests a lose connection that can be shaken closed again. Open it up, see if any circuit board is cracked, see if anything (esp. connectors) are coming free from the circuit boards, make sure any pluggable wires are firmly connected (the panel and controlling circuit board may be built so they can unplug from each other).